# Converting oracle.sql.STRUCT@ using python (into geojson or dataframe)

Tags: python, sql, oracle, type-conversion, shapefile

I would like to convert an Oracle DB frame including a **'SHAPE'** column that hold the **'oracle.sql.STRUCT@'** information into something more accessible, either a geojson/shapefile/dataframe either using **Python/R or SQL**.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create your frame with a query using one of the SDO_UTIL functions to convert the shape (sdo_geometry type) to a type easily consumed by Python/R, i.e. wkb, wkt, geojson. For example SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(shape). See info on the conversion functions here; https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html